Converting XY coordinates into local coordinate system using Arcade
I am currently trying to convert coordinates into a local county coordinate system. The use case is when I have my field workers out collecting, it could auto calculate a field for the geometry.x and y for the local system. Since most of our maps are in web auxiliary sphere. It would be easy if it auto calculate. I am trying to see if it’s possible, without calculating geometric attributes on the back end.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You seem to be looking for an Arcade projectAs Geometry Function which is an existing ArcGIS Pro Idea which is currently Under Consideration:

Working primarily with data in UTM projection, I often need ways to
convert UTM coordinates to WGS to create deep links to various online
services.
Having to create duplicate datasets, or running python scripts as
regular intervals is tedious and time consuming.
And arcade equivalent of the python projectAs method would solve
almost all these issues.

